# Perform extra validation after a Student signs into Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. We host a University Moodle site and we are looking for a way in which we can perform extra validation on a Student whenever they login. I will give a scenario.

We have an endpoint with a list of email addresses of students allowed to use the system, for example a list of Students who are fully paid up on tuition. Therefore, we are looking for a way to hook into the login process, perform this check and the allow the student to continue or redirect back to the login page with an error.

I would appreciate any advice on how we can achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. I ended up creating a custom Authentication plugin using the guidelines from https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins. With that knowledge, I used the copied the folder in the Moodle installation path `auth/none` and used that as a shell for my new plugin. I went ahead and customized the plugin names to what I needed. Once that was done and once the plugin was installed and enabled from the Administrator Dashboard, I had something like this in my `auth.php` file:

```
// Required for all auth plugins
public function user_login($username, $password)
{
    return false;
}

// Hooks in immediately after the User submits the login form
public function loginpage_hook()
{
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'] ?? '';

    /** CODE CHECKING IF USERNAME IS ALLOWED TO ACCESS MOODLE **/
    /** FOR EXAMPLE CHECK IF USER PAID FEES **/    
    $userHasPaidFees = api_checks_if_user_paid_fees($username);

    if ($userHasPaidFees ) {
        // Returning true here proceeds with the 
        // normal Username/Password login combination
        return true;
    }
    
    // If not, redirect them back to Login
    // Or any other page and notify
    redirect(
        new moodle_url('/login/index.php'), 
        'Message telling user why they were not able to sign in',
        null,
        \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_ERROR
    );
}
```

Thanks and I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: This solution seems to make it possible for anybody to check whether another member paid their fees as the check is done before the user and password have been validated.

Comment: @FMCorz that's true. Do you know any way that I can check AFTER the student has signed in? Thanks.

Comment: @realnsleo you can implement your checks AFTER the student credentials have been validated, by adding your hook inside the user_login($username, $password) function, before it returns true. It has to be BEFORE the functions returns true, but AFTER the credentials have been validated.

Comment: Thank you @RaymondMlambo. I have implemented that in my test platform and it seems to work great. I will edit the answer above with this. Thanks again.